# MySQL table data in Memory for read operation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, sqlite

It sounds odd but we have table which contain `millions` rows of data, and we are running query with `JOIN`, `AND`, `ORDER BY` etc operation, because of that Query running slow, Query scanning full table and finding best match result, currently single query taking 2 to 3 second which is not acceptable :(

Can i load full table in `Memory` and do read operation their? We are not writing data in table so we don't care about lost of data on `power off` we can quick load table in memory again if need.

I have tried all customization etc. using `mysqltunner` but didn't help.

Do you guy suggest loading table in Memory will help in `read` operation?

Other solution we have is `sqlite` put file on `memory` and run query on it.

## Table:

```
| lcr   | CREATE TABLE `lcr` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `digits` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` float(11,5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `intrastate_rate` float(11,5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `intralata_rate` float(11,5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `carrier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_strip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trail_strip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prefix` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `suffix` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `lcr_profile` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_start` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  `date_end` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2030-12-31 00:00:00',
  `quality` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `reliability` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `cid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `lrn` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `carrier_id` (`carrier_id`),
  KEY `digits` (`digits`),
  KEY `lcr_profile` (`lcr_profile`),
  KEY `rate` (`rate`),
  KEY `digits_profile_cid_rate` (`digits`,`rate`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `carrier_id` FOREIGN KEY (`carrier_id`) REFERENCES `carriers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1130954 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

In table we have following data. total rows 1.2 millions around

```
mysql> select * from lcr LIMIT 0,10;
+-----+--------+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-----+---------+-----+
| id  | digits | rate    | intrastate_rate | intralata_rate | carrier_id | lead_strip | trail_strip | prefix | suffix | lcr_profile | date_start          | date_end            | quality  | reliability | cid | enabled | lrn |
+-----+--------+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-----+---------+-----+
|   1 | 91     | 0.00010 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2015-09-11 15:53:39 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
|   2 | 91     | 0.01000 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2015-09-11 15:53:39 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
|   8 | 1      | 0.00700 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2013-09-11 16:56:38 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       0 |   0 |
|   9 | 91     | 0.00100 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2015-09-11 15:53:39 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       0 |   0 |
| 130 | 1844   | 0.00000 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2013-12-08 20:03:45 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
| 131 | 998    | 0.07070 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2014-02-11 09:20:00 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
| 132 | 9989   | 0.09490 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2014-02-11 09:20:00 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
| 133 | 99899  | 0.09490 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2014-02-11 09:20:00 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
| 134 | 99898  | 0.09490 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2014-02-11 09:20:00 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
| 135 | 99897  | 0.09490 |            NULL |           NULL |         13 |          0 |           0 |        |        |           0 | 2014-02-11 09:20:00 | 2015-02-28 00:00:00 | 0.000000 |    0.000000 |     |       1 |   0 |
+-----+--------+---------+-----------------+----------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-----+---------+-----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Query:

```
mysql> SELECT l.digits AS lcr_digits, c.carrier_name AS lcr_carrier_name, l.rate AS lcr_rate_field,  cg.prefix AS lcr_gw_prefix, cg.suffix AS lcr_gw_suffix, l.lead_strip AS lcr_lead_strip, l.trail_strip AS lcr_trail_strip, l.prefix AS lcr_prefix, l.suffix AS lcr_suffix, cg.codec AS lcr_codec, l.cid AS lcr_cid FROM lcr l JOIN carriers c ON l.carrier_id=c.id  JOIN carrier_gateway cg ON c.id=cg.carrier_id  WHERE c.enabled = '1' AND cg.enabled = '1' AND l.enabled = '1' AND ( (digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033, 1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1)     AND lrn = false) OR  (digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033, 1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1) AND lrn = true)) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN date_start AND date_end ORDER BY digits DESC, rate, rand();

+------------+------------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| lcr_digits | lcr_carrier_name | lcr_rate_field | lcr_gw_prefix | lcr_gw_suffix           | lcr_lead_strip | lcr_trail_strip | lcr_prefix | lcr_suffix | lcr_codec | lcr_cid |
+------------+------------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 1662303    | abc           |        0.00395 |               | @sip.abc.com        |              0 |               0 |            |            |           |         |
| 1          | xyz        |        0.00980 | 73734599*     | @sip.xyz.com      |              0 |               0 |            |            |           |         |
| 1          | Silver    |        0.01020 |               | @sip.Silver.com |              0 |               0 |            |            |           |         |
+------------+------------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+
3 rows in set (2.06 sec)
```

It scan `digit` with query provided digit and find value from other tables but those tables are very small only few entries there, It took `2 sec` but when multiple query runs then it hit CPU load.

Comment: FLOAT(m,n) is almost always 'wrong'.  It says (1) round to "n" decimal places, then round to the binary precision of FLOAT.  Plus it says to do something nasty if the number is bigger than m & n specify.  Why have two roundings?  Either use DECIMAL(m,n) or plain FLOAT.

Answer (score 0):

Your million rows are probably already in memory.  That is, MyISAM and InnoDB have caching techniques that are often effective at loading and keeping loaded the index and/or data that you need.

Please show us the query, plus SHOW CREATE TABLE.  There could be techniques that can greatly speed up the query.  One example is a typical 10x speed up for Data Warehouse "reports" by using Summary tables.  Simpler techniques involve a "compound" index, or a "covering" index.  Or rephrasing a WHERE clause to avoid hiding an indexed column inside a function call.  Sometimes, even reformulating a SELECT to use a subquery can speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible speedups.  (I say "possible" because of how complex the query is.)

1. Add INDEX(date_start), INDEX(date_end)
2. Observe that `lrn` is irrelevant in this OR:

   ```
     AND  ( (digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033,
                               1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1)
                     AND  lrn = false)
        OR  (digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033,
                               1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1)
                     AND  lrn = true) 
          )
   ```

   and simplify it down to

   ```
     AND  digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033,
                               1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1)
   ```
3. Start with a subquery containing the things that are filtered in `l`:

> ```
> SELECT  id
>     FROM  lcr AS l
>     WHERE  l.enabled = '1'
>       AND  ( (digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033,
>                          1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1) AND  lrn = false)
>          OR  (digits IN (16623033747, 1662303374, 166230337, 16623033,
>                          1662303, 166230, 16623, 1662, 166, 16, 1) AND  lrn = true) 
>            )
>       AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN date_start AND date_end;
> ```

together with an `INDEX(enabled, digits, lrn, date_start, date_end, id)` -- This needs to start with enabled (because of the '='), but the order of the rest does not matter much.

Then, build the rest of the query around it, including a "self join" back to lcr:

```
SELECT  l.digits AS lcr_digits, c.carrier_name AS lcr_carrier_name,
        l.rate AS lcr_rate_field, cg.prefix AS lcr_gw_prefix,
        cg.suffix AS lcr_gw_suffix, l.lead_strip AS lcr_lead_strip,
        l.trail_strip AS lcr_trail_strip, l.prefix AS lcr_prefix,
        l.suffix AS lcr_suffix, cg.codec AS lcr_codec, l.cid AS lcr_cid
    FROM  ( <the subquery above> ) l2
    JOIN  lcr l USING(id)
    JOIN  carriers c ON l.carrier_id=c.id
    JOIN  carrier_gateway cg ON c.id=cg.carrier_id
    WHERE  c.enabled = '1'
      AND  cg.enabled = '1'
    ORDER BY  l.digits DESC, l.rate, rand();
```

The principle behind this reformulation is to do pick the `id`s using only an index (the new one I mentioned), then reach for all the other stuff.  This has two "speedups":

(a) The "other stuff" is not being hauled around while doing all the filtering, and

(b) Using the index requires scanning less stuff.  (Plus we are filtering on `enabled` and maybe `digits` in the index.)

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for any SELECT you would like to discuss further.